# How do I escape quotation marks in Match.Regex properly?

Tags: c#

Testbed: http://regexhero.net/tester/

**Input String**: `"_sql": "SELECT * FROM AA"`
**Regex**: `(?:"_sql"[\s]*)([^,]*)`

**Desired result**: "SELECT * FROM AA"

Now I went into c# and coded this up:

```
    Match match = Regex.Match("_sql\": \"SELECT * FROM AA", @"(?:""_sql""[\s]*)([^,]*)");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        String value = match.Groups[0].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

Why is the `match.Success` false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot to put quotes `" "` around your string'.

Try-

```
Match match = Regex.Match("\"_sql\": \"SELECT * FROM AA\"", @"(?:""_sql""[\s]*)([^,]*)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate variable, and properly escape it.

```
string newVa = "\"_sql\": \"SELECT * FROM AA\"";
Match match = Regex.Match(newVa , @"(?:""_sql""[\s]*)([^,]*)");
```

or

```
Match match = Regex.Match(@"""_sql"": ""SELECT * FROM AA""", @"(?:""_sql""[\s]*)([^,]*)");
```